# Using an object as a property key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is going on in this code?

```
var a = {a:1};
var b = {b:2};
var c = {};

c[a] = 1;
c[b] === 1 // true!

c[b] = 2;
c[a] === 2 // true!
```

Specifically, why does using looking up `b` in `c` return the value that was stored in a property of `a`?

What does it mean to use an object as a key to a property in JavaScript?

I've tested this in Chrome/Node and in Firefox.

Comment: currently javascript does not have support for object as a key it probably get coherse (converted to) string which will be [object Object] and store the value hence it gives true to every object as a key, but in future 'Map' is something you can use to store object as a key.

Comment: Sounds interesting @Sushil. Do you have a reference to information about this potential future Map class? I couldn't find it mentioned anywhere after a few minutes of searching.

Comment: its a future implementation for ECMAScript 6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map here u go and additionally there is a very nice WeakMap concept (i personally like it) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap here u can read about it

Comment: Specification: [Property Accessors](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors) → [EvaluatePropertyAccessWithExpressionKey](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-evaluate-property-access-with-expression-key) → [ToPropertyKey](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-topropertykey). A property key is obtained by either keeping the symbol value or coercing the value to a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What does it mean to use an object as a key to a property in JavaScript?

Javascript objects only allow string keys, so your object will first be coerced to a string.

> Specifically, why does using looking up b in c return the value that was stored in a property of a?

The string representation of `{a: 1}` and `{b: 2}` are *both* `"[object Object]"`, thus, the property is overwritten.

**Edit:** *If* you really need to use objects as keys (I would prefer another solution, if possible), you could use the object's JSON representation:

```
c[JSON.stringify(a)] = 1
c[JSON.stringify(b)] = 2
```

But, again, try to think of a different approach. Perhaps the objects have unique identifiers other than the object itself.

Comment: Cheers Linus, this makes good sense. I do need to use objects as keys in a sense, so an actual `Map` class would be useful. However I won't have very many in my set, so I think I'll just create an array of key/value pairs, and on 'get' loop through them, testing keys with `===`. It'll be O(N), but my N will be around 10 so I'm not bothered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Why you use an object as a key, 
the key is becoming the `object.toString()` 's result which is `[Object Object]`,

So what you are dothing is set a value to the property `"[Object Object]"`, and get the value by the property `"[Object Object]"`.