# Custom Class JS Object Access Result

Tags: javascript

I encountered a weird JS behavior during a mock interview and I'm just curious why this occurs. Here is a minimal reproduce case:

```js
class Association {}
class Document {}
class Post extends Document {}
class User extends Document {}

let [ u1, u2 ] = [new User(), new User()]
let [ p1, p2, p3 ] = [ new Post(), new Post(), new Post() ]

let posts = new Association(User, Post, "posts")

let database = {
  [u1]: { [posts]: [ p1, p2 ] },
  [u2]: { [posts]: [ p3 ] },
}

console.log("HERE", database[u1][posts]) // [ Post {} ]
```

Why is the result only 1 post? Shouldn't it be 2 as defined in the database?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I wouldn't use `Document` as a class name since it is already a global property

Comment: Object properties must be strings. If you use something other than a string, it will be stringified. Both your `User` classes will serialise to the same value. If you want rich keys, use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Would overriding the toString or hashCode method fix this?

Comment: See [Using an object as a property key in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12386450/283366) and [Javascript object literal - possible to add duplicate keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38790146/283366)

Comment: @NeilShweky yes but each instance would have to return a different value to be used as individual keys within the same object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object property names can ONLY be strings or Symbols. We can ignore Symbols here. If you actually want to use objects as a key, then you can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

`[u1]: { [posts]: [ p1, p2 ] },`

This ☝️ line adds a property named `[Object object]` to the `database` object. It sets the value associated with that property to a new object that itself is initialised with a property named `[Object object]` whose value is set to be an array containing `p1` and `p2`.

`[u2]: { [posts]: [ p3 ] },`

This ☝️ line **overwrites** the value of the property named `[Object object]` with a reference to a new object that has one property named `[Object object]` that has a value of an array containing `p3`.

When referring to an object property with the bracket syntax `[<expression>]`, the expression is first evaluated, and the result is then coerced (because JS is weakly typed) to a string, if need be, to form the property name.

`u1` and `u2` are objects. Using an object as a property key will, by default, result in a  call to the abstract internal operation [*OrdinaryToPrimitive*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) with the hint `'string'`. This will invoke `Object.prototype.toString()`, and this will, by default, result in the string `'[Object object]'`.

Note that you can override various aspects of this coercion behavior; for example, by implementing your own `Symbol.toStringTag` getter method:

```js
class Association {}
class Document {}
class Post extends Document {}
class User extends Document {}

let [ u1, u2 ] = [new User(), new User()]
let [ p1, p2, p3 ] = [ new Post(), new Post(), new Post() ]
let posts = new Association(User, Post, "posts")

Object.defineProperty(u1, Symbol.toStringTag, {
  get() { return 'u1' }
})

let database = {
  [u1]: { [posts]: [ p1, p2 ] },
  [u2]: { [posts]: [ p3 ] },
}

console.log("HERE", JSON.stringify(database))
```

[More details here](https://javascript.info/object-toprimitive).